# Application Load Balancer return 504Gateway Timeout

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a rails app run on ECS Fargate.
Application Load Balancer in the front and ECS service also uses Auto Scaling Group.
It acts as normal until I have to handle with batch.
When I send 500 requests it is ok.

```
ab -c 500 -n 500 -r -T 'application/json' -p file.json -H "Authorization: $token" https://example.com/api
```

But when I send 1000 requests or 2000 request, response has some Failed requests. If I try again, the number is different. I checked the logs and see that failed requests was 504Gateway Timeout. And no more details.

When I send 5000 requests,

```
the ECS service ... (port 3000) is unhealthy in target-group ... due to(reason Request timed out).
```

I tried to raise up RAILS_MAX_THREAD and CONCUURENT_WORKER but no luck.
Anyone has some suggestion ? Please tell me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in my web server.
I increase the concurrent thread to 16 and worker to 6.
And in ab command -c set to 100.
It becomes fine again.